# Range.Find method not always works properly

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the fragment of my procedure which sometimes doesn't work and I don't have any idea why?

```
With wbSourceFile.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 2).EntireColumn
    Set rngDataStart = .Find(What:=CLng(strSheetName), _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                             MatchCase:=True, _
                             LookAt:=xlPart, _
                             After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count))
End With
```

This `Range.Find` method should look for a cell in `wbSourceFile` workbook (to be precise: in column B of the first worksheet of this workbook) which value is equal to a name of the sheet from the 2nd excel file (this name is previously stored in `strSheetName` string variable and complies with the mask "1630?????" where '?' stands for any digit).

Generally it works. But the problem is that it doesn't work all the time. There were at least a few times when the `rngDataStart` variable was set to 'Nothing', although there was an appropriate value in the searched range! And what's even stranger: when I enter the debug mode and run the procedure step by step the problem disappears (`Range.Find` method starts to work correctly).

Of course I have to ensure that `Range.Find` method will work properly every time. So I need any suggestion what could cause this situation or where should I look for a reason of that strange behavior?

Comment: Is the value you are searching for stored in the cell as a constant, or is the cell calculating it by a formula?  (I'm wondering whether you have manually used a "Look in: Formulas" just prior to it crashing, but at other times you have manually used a "Look in: Values" just prior to it working.)

Comment: The value is always stored in the cell as a constant (there is no formulas in this sheet, because this file contents only raw data exported from other application). And the format of this cell is 'General'.

Comment: OK, that blows that theory out of the water,

Comment: I just noticed that your posted code doesn't include line continuation characters. (I tried to paste it into a macro to see whether I could break it and, of course, got a syntax error.)  That implies that you didn't copy/paste the code from VBE into the question, which means that there is potentially some difference between what is in the question and what you are actually running.  For the moment I will assume you had one long line and the line breaks are the **only** difference between this code and your code - but can you please verify that.

Comment: put this line before the code that you posted  `debug.print CLng(strSheetName)` or just `debug.print strSheetName` .... when the code "fails", check the `Immediate` window for the printed value

Comment: Yeah, you're right. The only difference between this two codes are the line breaks. I've changed it just after paste, to improve readability. Edit: I correct the code, now it should be OK.

Comment: @jsotola: The problem is that I've tried to repeat this situation and I failed to :( It happened only 2 or 3 times and only on my customer's computer.

Comment: put in code `if rngDataStart  is nothing then` .... `msgbox "an error has occured ..blah blah.`   ..... have it show the value of `strSheetName` and ask to call you to give you the "errror code" (sheetname)

Comment: Intermittent errors are the hardest to debug!  @jsotola's suggestion is probably the best you can do at the moment.  (The only things I can think of that might cause the problem is the user adding an extra sheet to the workbook before running the macro, so that the sheet you are meant to be searching is no longer `Worksheets(1)`, or something wrong in your code where it is setting `wbSourceFile`.)

Comment: @YowE3K: I know that it is hard to help find something which isn't repeatable.. but I don't give up and will still try to discover the reason why the error occurrs, so for sure I will use your advices :) Thanks for all your suggestions.

Comment: @jsotola: The code you mentioned above (with MsgBox which displays the strSheetName in case when rngDataStart is 'Nothing') is already in my procedure a few lines below: `If rngDataStart Is Nothing Then` ... `MsgBox "There is no data for project " & strSheetName & " in the source file!"` and unfortunately when the error occured MsgBox displayed the correct name of the sheet.

Comment: I also checked it step by step in the debug mode and: the value of strSheetName was "163020040", there was a sheet in the workbook named "163020040", there was a cell with value "163020040" in the source file, and despite all this the result of the Range.Find method was: rngDataStart = 'Nothing'. Any ideas how is it possible?

Comment: @jsotola: Responding to your previous question: after removing the conversion function `CLng` from the code (searching for a String value instead of Long), everything still works fine.

Comment: when it happens again check the value of the cell by looking at the formula bar.  ... maybe something will show up ... could it be a unicode issue?

Comment: And was there definitely only one worksheet in the workbook referred to by `wbSourceFile`?  Perhaps another hidden sheet?

Comment: @YowE3K: Yes, only one worksheet in the workbooks with source data, no Hidden or VeryHidden sheets.

Comment: @jsotola: What do you mean _could it be a unicode issue?_ Can you explain it to me?

Comment: Some of the unicode characters look very similar to normal characters (although I'm not sure whether any look like numbers) and some unicode characters aren't even visible.  Next time an error occurs, try typing a formula such as `=B30="163020040"` (where `B30` is whatever cell you **think** should be matching, and `"163020040"` is whatever has been displayed as `strSheetName`) into a cell somewhere and see if it returns `TRUE`.  If not, **copy/paste** the value in the cell, and the value of `strSheetName` into the question and ping @jsotola or myself and we will be happy to investigate.

Comment: @YowE3K: Ok. Now I understand :) It looks like I have no choice than to wait until the error reappears. Of course, I'll let you know when I get the error again or find the cause :) Thanks again for your feedback.